# Order by date in firebase real-time database

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-tools

I'm doing a query for retrieving data ordered by date.

The JSON Tree:

```
{
  results: {
    first:{
      created_at: "ISOstring"
    },
    second:{
      created_at: "ISOstring"
    },
    etc:{
      created_at: "ISOstring"
    }
  }
}
```

In my firebase service file I do such query with orderByChild

```
async function getLastFive() {
  const resultsRef = ref(db, 'results')
  const lastFiveResultsQuery = query(resultsRef, orderByChild("created_at"), limitToLast(5))
  
  try {
    const response = await get(lastFiveResultsQuery)
    const firebaseResults = response.val() as FirebaseResults
    const output = firebaseResultsToArray(firebaseResults)
    return output
  } catch (error) {
    throw error
  }
}
```

And I have an error.

> Error: Index not defined, add ".indexOn": "created_at", for path "/results", to the rules
> at eval (index.esm2017.js?3595:11058:1)
> at async Object.getLastFive (database.ts?5927:51:22)

I don't know why this error occured, because I've configured .indexOn in firebase.json file (below)
I use database emulators and I configured firebase.json.

```
{
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "emulators": {
    "database": {
      "port": 9000,
      "rules": "database.rules.json"
    },
    "auth": {
      "port": 5001
    },
    "ui": {
      "enabled": true
    },
    "singleProjectMode": true
  }
}
```

And see database.rules.json

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
    "results": {
      ".indexOn": "created_at"
    }
  }
}
```

What to do with this error?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I solved the problem by changing database connection URL from http://127.0.0.1:9000/?ns=fir-3480f to http://127.0.0.1:9000/?ns=fir-3480f-default-rtdb.

fir-3480f - name of Firebase Project